# Apache2 stop command missing

Tags: apache2

How do I stop my local apache server?

`/etc/init.d/apache2` and `service apache2` give only 3 options -- `restart`, `start`and `status`

---

I rebooted my syetem and now `sudo /etc/inid.d/apache stop` works but doesn't give the `stop` option on <kbd>TAB</kbd>

`httpd` was missing so I did `sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/apachectl /etc/init.d/httpd` -- read it on some forum

The httpd service now gives `start` and `status` option (Again, no `stop`)

doing `sudo /etc/init.d/httpd status` says

```
Looking up localhost
Making HTTP connection to localhost
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://localhost/server-status
'www-browser -dump http://localhost:80/server-status' failed.
Maybe you need to install a package providing www-browser or you
need to adjust the APACHE_LYNX variable in /etc/apache2/envvars
```

I did install lynx just before making the link by `sudo apt-get install lynx`

Why is only the `stop` missing? This is just plain weird ...

Comment: have you tried `sudo service apache2 stop`.. it has a stop command.. more > https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Run.2C_Stop.2C_Test.2C_And_Restart_Apache

Comment: Yes I did, it says `stop: Unknown job: apache2`

Comment: `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl stop` says `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`  `httpd (pid 1491?) not running`

Comment: Could you just backup its configuration and reinstall it?

Comment: I tried re-installing but as I've read in many places, `apache2` is a meta-package, and I think many of its dependencies were installed manually so finding and removing all of them is not possible (for me at least)

Comment: Actually, it has 4 main packages: apache2, apache2-bin, apache2-data, apache2-utils. I would recommend `sudo apt-get install synaptic`. Run it, Change to *Status*, Select *Installed*, search for apache2. Select the 4 packages, Right click *Mark for Complete Removal*. Then Install Apache2 again. Otherwise `sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils`, `sudo apt-get install apache2`

Comment: So neither this one help (`sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils; sudo apt-get install apache2`)?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but no it didn't work. The `stop` is still missing

Answer (score 2):

Here's how i kill it:

```
$ sudo service apache2 stop
```

make sure it is off, or that the process isn't running

```
ps -elf | grep apache
0 S j0h      14733 24786  0  80   0 -  1108 pipe_w 08:22 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

(says the only instance of Apache is my query)

Starting back up:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Other methods, include

```
$sudo service apache2 graceful-stop
```

You could kill apache2 many other ways:

```
$sudo pkill apache2

$sudo kill -9 <apache PID>
```

(find apache's pid ps aux | grep apac) or use top to find the PID of apache2)

This line:

> sudo /etc/inid.d/apache stop

you probably meant init.d

That might just be a typo though, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the apache2ctl command.

```
sudo apache2ctl stop
```

That handles the service and all in a short command. Other commands like `start`, `restart` are also supported.

Answer (score 1):

Okay! Apache is restarting successfully but just isn't sure where that it want serve from, as it is choosing your localhost (127.0.0.1) by default. To prevent this message from appearing, add the following line into your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file:

```
ServerName localhost
```

P.S.: Make sure that you want to serve from localhost (127.0.0.1)

**More:** [How to fix Apache – "Could not reliably determine the server’s fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName" Error on Ubuntu](http://aslamnajeebdeen.com/blog/how-to-fix-apache-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-using-127011-for-servername-error-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Now `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl stop` says `httpd (pid 19157?) not running`. `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file is missing, is that weird?

Comment: Okay! may be the file is not listed under conf.. try adding `Include httpd.conf` at the end of `apache2.conf` file then restart the service. let me know how it goes.. Also make sure you back up each file before you do any changes. :)

Comment: I think the missing `httpd.conf` is normal. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2116503

Answer (score 1):

$ sudo service apache2 stop

worked for me . I was getting error while starting tomcat7 in eclipse but it show error "Port already in use for 8080 and 8005" as the ports were already acquired by apache2 (i.e for php server).